# How to find the gradient vector and hessian of a summation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to find the gradient vector and Hessian of the following summation:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n [(x_i +b_i)^4 + e^{2x_i}]
$$

Trying to find the gradient vector:

$\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$, so we need to work out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n [4(x_i +b_i)^3 + 2e^{2x_i}]$

= $ 4\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i +b_i)^3 + 2\sum_{i=1}^ne^{2x_i}$

From here, I don't really know how to continue finding the gradient vector.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Quoka I want to understand how to continue finding the gradient vector. I have no idea how to expand the summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be clearer to calculate the gradient vector if you wrote out the sum explicitly:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[(x_i+b_i)^4+e^{2x_i}] $$ $$= (x_1+b_1)^4+e^{2x_1}+(x_2+b_2)^4+e^{2x_2}+\ldots+(x_j+b_j)^4+e^{2x_j}+\ldots+(x_n+b_n)^4+e^{2x_n} $$
for some $1\leq j\leq n$. Computing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$, we arrive at:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = 4(x_j+b_j)^3+2e^{2x_j}$$
Since the gradient is the vector of partial derivatives, we have:
$$\nabla f = \left(4(x_1+b_1)^3+2e^{2x_1},\ldots, 4(x_j+b_j)^3+2e^{2x_j},\ldots, 4(x_n+b_n)^3+2e^{2x_n} \right)$$
The Hessian will be an $n\times n$ matrix, where the $ij$th entry is found according to $H_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\right)$. Notice that for $i\neq j $, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\right) = 0$, since in the $j$th component of the gradient, there is no dependency on $x_{i}$. For $i=j $, we have that 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(4(x_j+b_j)^3+2e^{2x_j}\right) = 12(x_j+b_j)^2+4e^{2x_j}$$
Then you end up with:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 12(x_1+b_1)^2+4e^{2x_1} & 0& 0 & \cdots &  0\\
 0 & 12(x_2+b_2)^2+4e^{2x_2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 12(x_n+b_n)^2+4e^{2x_n}    
 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

Answer (score 1):

One has
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[(x_j+b_j)^4 + e^{2x_j}\right].
$$
Now, note that if $i\neq j$ then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[(x_j+b_j)^4 + e^{2x_j}\right] = 0.
$$
If $i=j$, the we simply compute the derivative;
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[(x_i+b_i)^4 + e^{2x_i}\right] = 4(x_i+b_i)^3 + 2e^{2x_i}.
$$
We conclude that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 4(x_i+b_i)^3 + 2e^{2x_i}.
$$
So the gradient vector is
$$
\nabla f = \left(4(x_1+b_1)^3 + 2e^{2x_1}, \dots, 4(x_n+b_n)^3 + 2e^{2x_n}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

For typing convenience, define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
y &= x+b \quad&\implies\quad &dy = dx \\
w &= y\odot y \quad&\implies\quad &dw = 2y\odot dy \;\implies\;
y\odot dw = 2 w\odot dy\\
e &= \exp(x) \;&\implies\quad &de = e\odot dx \\
}$$
and the diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
W &= \operatorname{Diag}(w) \quad&\implies\quad Wz &= w\odot z 
\quad\big({\rm for\,an\,arbitrary\,vector\,}z\big) \\
E &= \operatorname{Diag}(e) \quad&\implies\quad Ez &= e\odot z \\
Y &= \operatorname{Diag}(y) \quad&\implies\quad W &= Y^2 = (X+B)^2 \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables, then calculate the gradient $(g)$.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= w:w + e:e \\
df &= 2w:dw + 2e:de \\
 &= 2w:(2y\odot dy) + 2e:(e\odot dx) \\
 &= (4y\odot w):dy + (2e\odot e):dx \\
 &= (4y\odot w + 2e\odot e):dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 4y\odot w + 2e\odot e \;\doteq\; g \\
}$$
Now calculate the gradient of the gradient, i.e. the Hessian $(H)$.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= 4\,(dy\odot w + y\odot dw) + 2\,(de\odot e + e\odot de) \\
 &= 4\left(w\odot dy + y\odot dw + e\odot de\right) \\
 &= 4\left(w\odot dy + 2w\odot dy + e\odot e\odot dx\right) \\
 &= 4\left(3w + e\odot e\right)\odot dx \\
 &= \left(12W + 4E^2\right)dx \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \left(12Y^2 + 4E^2\right) \;\doteq\; H \\
}$$

---

In the above, $(\odot)$ is used to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product, while a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Interestingly, the Hessian is a diagonal matrix.